# MalformedURLException on wildfly standalone properties file path

Tags: linux, windows, wildfly, wildfly-10

I am trying to use UsersRolesLoginModule for one of my applications. Configuration below works perfectly fine on my windows machine. When I use the exact same configuration on linux environment, I am getting MalformedURLException. I specified linux&windows because I assume that's the problem here.

I tried to add `file://` before the value but then something more weird things happened. Wildfly deployed my apps without any problem but I was not able to reach out my apps through browsers. I was getting 404 error.

Any ideas/suggestions would be great.

```
 <security-domain name="app" cache-type="default">
     <authentication>
         <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule" flag="required">
             <module-option name="usersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/app-users.properties"/>
             <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/app-roles.properties"/>
         </login-module>
     </authentication>
  </security-domain>

PBOX00287: Failed to open properties file from URL: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /path/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/configuration/app-roles.properties
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:586)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:483)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:432)
        at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.Util.loadProperties(Util.java:200)
        at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule.loadRoles(UsersRolesLoginModule.java:231)
        at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule.createRoles(UsersRolesLoginModule.java:245)
        at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule.initialize(UsersRolesLoginModule.java:147)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:736)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
        at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.defaultLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:406)
        at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.proceedWithJaasLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:345)
        at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.authenticate(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:333)
        at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.isValid(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:146)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.JAASIdentityManagerImpl.verifyCredential(JAASIdentityManagerImpl.java:123)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.JAASIdentityManagerImpl.verify(JAASIdentityManagerImpl.java:94)
        at io.undertow.security.impl.BasicAuthenticationMechanism.authenticate(BasicAuthenticationMechanism.java:118)
        at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$AuthAttempter.transition(SecurityContextImpl.java:233)
        at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$AuthAttempter.transition(SecurityContextImpl.java:250)
        at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$AuthAttempter.access$100(SecurityContextImpl.java:219)
        at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.attemptAuthentication(SecurityContextImpl.java:121)
        at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.authTransition(SecurityContextImpl.java:96)
        at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.authenticate(SecurityContextImpl.java:89)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:55)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

This message can be safely ignored, it's the UsersRoles login module checking for all it's options. If the defaultUsersProperties or defaultRolesProperties aren't defined it will write that message in the log when org.jboss.security is set to DEBUG or TRACE